# How to evaluate length of side of triangle

Tags: geometry

I came across the following question whilst preparing for the GRE exam, where only a basic calculator with no trigonometric functions is allowed.

[image: Question Image]

The question asks which quantity is bigger, the length AC or the value 3.

Is there a way I can answer this question without explicitly computing the value of any trigonometric function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the base of the vertical line D.  BCD is half an equilateral triangle, so  $CD=1$.  BD is less than $2$ (it is $\sqrt 3$, which you can find from Pythagoras, but we don't need that.)  ABD is an isosceles triangle, so $AD=BD$ and is less than $2$.  Therefore $AC \lt 3$

Comment: I think the key to solving this problem quickly was to notice that BCD is half of an equilateral triangle.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This question expects you to already know the properties of two types of triangles.

First, let the intersection of AC and the altitude of triangle ABC be called point D.

1. In a 30-60-90 triangle, the side lengths are in the ratio 1:$\sqrt{3}$:2

   Since we are given that BC=2, BD=$\sqrt{3}$ and **DC=1**
2. In a 45-45-90 triangle, the side lengths are in the ratio 1:1:$\sqrt{2}$

   Since we have determined that BD=$\sqrt{3}$, **AD=$\sqrt{3}$** as well (and    AB=$\sqrt{6}$).

Lastly, since we know AD+DC=AC

AC=1+$\sqrt{3}$

Since 3 = 1+2 = 1+$\sqrt{4}$, we can conclude that 3 > AC